# Git -> Version control for 3 separate code base paths

Tags: git

I'm an electrical engineering trying to learn software tools to help me do my job. I'm getting quite familiar with git but not nearly as fluent as the experts on here.

I have an automated test system to test hardware devices using several pieces of instruments and a proprietary (legacy) software automation tool.

The software tool uses a text file to outline all test cases to be covered and how to test them, and this file uses a specific syntax.

However, we are using a single hardware platform for multiple product all of which have small variations from one to the other (i.e. frequency variants. For the sake of the argument, imagine we are changing certain words in the test file to different synonyms based on the geographic location.  North America we use the word "Thanks!" , if we're selling in UK we use "Cheers!" , if we're selling in canada we use "Regards".

As we develop the code base there are multiple files for different test scenarios>

However, each frequency variant will need the SAME files but each file will have those synonyms change.

As we continue development, we'll have to make changes to each file (add more lines of test cases, correct errors)  and those changes must be made onto the other Frequency Variant files.

### Unfortunately we cannot have all the files co-exist on the same folder, otherwise our automated system would see conflicts.

So the way I'm trying to do this is:

Great git repo for TestDefinitions
The testdefinition files will be stored inside the folder with the appropriate name
- Transmit_Test.txt
- Receive_Test.txt
- Compliance_test.txt

Then basically have different branches for each frequency variant:
- Master (generic template)
- Frequency_1
- Frequency_2
- Frequency_3

then if i need to do a test on a product that'sa different variant, i simply check out a differnet branch.

---

I don't think it's necessary to show some code at this point but if necesary, I can show dumps of what git repo looks like.

IS there a more effective way to do this?
I realise that i'm not using git in the  way it was designed,
and i'm worried we might have 3 branches diverging away from each other, and there might accidentally merge things we shouldn.t

SHould I keep this as is and manage changes independently?
Should I create 3 different repos?

Should I go back to copying and pasting?

Comment: From what you describe, branches is the approach I would probably take if the files cannot coexist.

Comment: If what you're doing is localization, as you describe, I'd recommend having a global variable of what localization you're in, and then a lookup for the different values. 
Or you could have your master template, and then a folder of frequency definitions and have your program pick the appropriate one for the current localization

Answer (score 1):

You could separate in branches, one for each frequency with their own feature, and one master branch with common features.

[image: Before]

Insted of merging branches, if you need to add a common feature to one of your frequency branches, you simply cherry-pick the feature you need.

For example, supose you need to add the common feature 4 on your frequency 2 branch, you could do something like this:

```
$ git checkout frequency2
$ git cherry-pick 8552d2ba # ID, branch or tag of the common feature to pick
```

The result would be

[image]

This way you could be selective about what goes to your frequency branches, keeping them independent.